# php strtok function not getting this example

Tags: php

What will be the output of following PHP code:

```
<?php

echo strtok("Hello world!","kHlleo");

?>
```

answer is `w`

can any one explain how it works to output w ?
i know strtok tokenise the string, but not understanding this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically returns a list with letters that are not filtered.
You filter the letters "kHlleo", out of "Hello world!", leaving w, r and d!.

```
$tok = strtok("Hello world!", "kHlleo");

while ($tok !== false) {
echo "Word=$tok<br />";
$tok = strtok("kHlleo");
}
```